# /dev/kvm is not found в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

установил андройд студию десятую , пытаюсь запустить эмулятор , увы не запускается пишет `/dev/kvm is not found`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также почитал ответы они как будто в из 10 -тире 16 года [были взяты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812624/android-studio-emulator-dev-kvm-is-not-found) по сути ни какой действительности с современностью.

так же пытался [ХАВМ установить](https://github.com/intel/haxm)  с гитхаба

```
(base) dima@komp:~/mita/тензорфлов/haxm-master/platforms/linux$ ./Makefile 
./Makefile: строка 1: shell: команда не найдена
./Makefile: строка 1: KVER: команда не найдена
./Makefile: строка 2: KVER: команда не найдена
./Makefile: строка 2: KDIR: команда не найдена
./Makefile: строка 4: shell: команда не найдена
./Makefile: строка 4: MACHINE: команда не найдена
./Makefile: строка 5: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «$(MACHINE),x86_64»
./Makefile: строка 5: `ifeq ($(MACHINE),x86_64)'
```

Также пытался какую то "чепушню" запустить :

```
(base) dima@komp:~/mita/тензорфлов/haxm-master/platforms/linux$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: For more detailed results, you should run this as root
HINT:   sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
(base) dima@komp:~/mita/тензорфлов/haxm-master/platforms/linux$ sudo modprobe kvm-intel
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported
(base) dima@komp:~/mita/тензорфлов/haxm-master/platforms/linux$ sudo modprobe kvm
(base) dima@komp:~/mita/тензорфлов/haxm-master/platforms/linux$ sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

Увы так и не заработало :(

---

Спасибо за советы ребят они помогли  Единственно не не могу обойти проблемму с директорией `/dev/kvm`
*создал её руками*

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm 
...
sudo adduser dima kvm

Добавляется пользователь «dima» в группу «kvm» ...
Добавление пользователя dima в группу kvm
Готово.

sudo chown dima /dev/kvm
chown: невозможно получить доступ к '/dev/kvm': Нет такого файла или каталога
cd /dev/
sudo mkdir kvm
sudo chown dima /dev/kvm
```

Но увы так и не запустилось, выводит тоже самое что и на первой картинке.

Comment: У Вас убунту, а ответы показываете для мака. Вот шаги: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003471/8343843

Comment: программа linux у вас запущена на реальном «железе»? если да, приложите к вопросу содержимое `/proc/cpuinfo`. если нет, то разбирайтесь с используемой системой виртуализации, в которой и запущена программа.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin увы у меня нету такой папки `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @AlexeyR.  увы действуя как там описанно не удалось запустить (я думаю это из за интела и бо интел это помойка которая вовсем проиграла  райзену)

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` — это файл. так программа linux запущена на реальном железе? значит, стоит воспользоваться вами же процитированным советом: *Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Александр Баракин , у меня в биосе визуализация была  скрыта в отдельной папке "цпу"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]