# падает эмулятор телефона в Android studio при запуске

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

При запуске эмулятора телефона, "падает" эмулятор телефона  и выдаёт такое ошибки :

```
15:14 Emulator: E0718 15:14:04.365500179 20001 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1595076184.365488346","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}

15:14 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал так :

С начало подключаем   виртуализацию (до подключения писалошибку что [не может найти директорию /dev/kvm и просто не создавал эмулятор телефона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152124/dev-kvm-is-not-found-%D0%B2-ubuntu)).

Теперь ставим пакеты виртуализации  :

```
 sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

и

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Перезагружаем  компьютер.

Заработало !!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]